# Cannot Create Instead of Trigger

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've got two SQL Server 2008 tables: Schedules (the parent) and ScheduleResults (the child)

```
CREATE TABLE Schedules(
    ID int identity primary key NOT NULL,
    Status nvarchar(3)
) [ON PRIMARY]
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE ScheduleResults(
    ID int identity primary key NOT NULL,
    ScheduleID int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [FK_ScheduleResults_Schedules] REFERENCES Schedules(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    IsEndOfRun bit NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_ScheduleResults_IsEndOfRun DEFAULT(0)
) [ON PRIMARY]
```

The logic is that after an insert/update/delete of the child, I look at all the children for the parent. If any of them have IsEndOfRun=1, then parent Schedules record status goes to 'DEA', otherwise it goes to 'ACT'. If none are found, it still goes to 'ACT'.

So here is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ScheduleResultsStatus
ON [ScheduleResults] AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @ScheduleID int
    DECLARE @IsEORSum int
    SELECT @ScheduleID=ScheduleID FROM inserted
    SELECT @IsEORSum=COUNT(*) FROM ScheduleResults WHERE ScheduleID=@ScheduleID AND IsEndOfRun=1

    IF @IsEORSum=0
    BEGIN
            -- There are no EndOfRun results. Schedule should be active
            UPDATE Schedules SET Status='ACT' WHERE ID=@ScheduleID
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
            -- There is at least 1 record with IsEndOfRun=True. Schedule should be DEACTIVATED
            UPDATE Schedules SET Status='DEA' WHERE ID=@ScheduleID
    END
```

After Insert works perfect. After Update works perfect. After Delete does not work. There is a warning squiggly over the trigger name with this message:

> Cannot create INSTEAD OF DELETE TRIGGER. This is because table has a foreign key with cascading delete.

My original definition did have a ON DELETE CASCADE clause on the ScheduleID column. I removed it, but no success. Also, as you can see I am creating an AFTER trigger, not an INSTEAD of trigger. So now my question... How do I tweak the Trigger and/or FK Constraint to let me take care of referential integrity and take care of the delete children scenarios?

I appreciate any help from all the SQL Server wizards.

Comment: Side note: seeing this statement `SELECT @ScheduleID=ScheduleID FROM inserted`, it appears that you think the trigger will be called once per row - this is **not** the case; the trigger will be called **once per statement**, and if that statement affects multiple rows, the `Inserted` pseudo table will have **multiple rows** in it. You need to write your trigger code in such a way that it can deal with multiple rows in `Inserted` - your code currently cannot do that.

Comment: Do you really need to **store** this status? - it seems like it would be a simple matter to compute it during retrieval (you could create a view that contains the logic if you wanted to)

Comment: And also, in addition to marc_s's comment - don't `COUNT()` when all you want to do is establish existence or not. `EXISTS()` exists for a reason.

Comment: And also: The inserted table stores copies of the affected rows during INSERT and UPDATE statements. During an insert or update transaction, new rows are added to both the inserted table and the trigger table. The rows in the inserted table are copies of the new rows in the trigger table. So your select will never return anything in case of delete.

Comment: marc_s, correct, I need to adjust the trigger to work with sets, not a single record.

Comment: Damien, the business rules I am dealing with require I set the flag on the record. I agree it would be better to use a view, but I'm a little stuck on this one. Also thanks for the catch on the EXISTS.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the previous comments. It sparked some thoughts and I was able to not only get it working, but the code is much simpler working with sets. Here's the code for posterity:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ScheduleResultsStatus
ON [ScheduleResults] AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE Schedules SET Status='ACT' WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT Schedules.ID FROM Schedules INNER JOIN deleted ON Schedules.ID=deleted.ScheduleID)
    UPDATE Schedules SET Status='DEA' WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT Schedules.ID FROM Schedules INNER JOIN inserted ON Schedules.ID=inserted.ScheduleID WHERE IsEndOfRun=1)
    UPDATE Schedules SET Status='ACT' WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT Schedules.ID FROM Schedules INNER JOIN inserted ON Schedules.ID=inserted.ScheduleID Group BY Schedules.ID HAVING SUM(CONVERT(int, IsEndOfRun))=0)
GO
```